# Maven fails with one project and works with another

Tags: eclipse, maven

im new to Maven and i've got some problems.. for example, i have 2 projects in my workspace and when i run commands like:

```
$ mvn install
$ mvn compile
$ mvn test
```

It gives me this kind of output:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.255 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-23T18:28:25-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile `(default-compile) on project flightsbookingcli: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:`
```

After looking for solutions i ran mvn dependency:list (in terminal) and fixed it partially, because now i can run these commands but only in one of my projects. Then started to look for solutions again and read a lot of posts saying something like this:

> Go to eclipse and window>preferences>Java>installed JRes and make sure that it's pointing to a JRe not jdk

Alright, i don't think that's a solution because it's pointing to my jdk (15.0.2), even if it is the solution i can't find the JRe within jdk folder (guess there's actually no jre within newest jdk versions).

Some information:

Maven version 3.6.3

SO Ubuntu 20.0.4

JAVA_HOME Configured

Before trying to solve it, maven complained several times about compile plugin, but i'm just executing a "Hello World!" project, think those plugins come by default.. so i probably set something wrong and i have no clue what, because i followed the installation steps perfectly

I think it's a dependencies trouble, or something like that.. maybe it's pointing to the wrong pom.xml file

[image: User settings]

Also i deleted the .m2/repository because a lot of users (here) recommended it, and tried to reindex but didnt know how.

I've been stuck for a while, hope you can help me, thanks in adnvance.

Comment: There is a compilation error in your project which means an error in your project ... this needs to be fixed `flightsbookingcli: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:` ...

Comment: Could you give any idea? I've generated the projects with the exactly same command and i haven't modified anything respectively to their folders

Comment: Your question contains only the end of the Maven output, which is just a summary. Details about the compiler error you have, including the location (file and line), you can find in the output above the summary.